# angular validation on an associative array

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a javascript object representing people and their roles. The roles are strings representing enums.

Here's an example:

```
{
    "532":"Customer",
    "545":"Employee",
    "335":"Manager"
}
```

To control the role assignment, I have the following mark-up:

```
<div ng-repeat="(personId, role) in people">
    {{personId}}
    <select ng-model="people[personId]">
        <option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role}}"                
                ng-selected="role === people[personId]">
            {{role}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now, I need to validate the role assignments so that there is exactly one employee and one employee and one manager.

I have a `<div>` elsewhere on that consolidates all validation messages.

I added some custom validation via `UI.Utils` to the `<select>` like so `ui-validate="{hasEmployee: 'hasEmployee($value)', hasManager : 'hasManager($value)' }"`.

I wrapped my `<select>` with an `ng-form` like so `<div ng-form="personDesignation">`

And I added some validation messages like so

```
<div>
    <div ng-show="myForm.personDesignation.$error.hasEmployee">
        A solution must have exactly one employee
    </div>
    <div ng-show="myForm.personDesignation.$error.hasManager">
        A solution must have exactly one manager
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the validation only works for the last select in my repeat. Changing the selections on all but the last select doesn't do anything. It makes sense, but I'm not sure what to do so that my validation roles up into my parent form. I have used `ng-form` within `ng-repeat` previously, but in those situations, my validation was also within the `ng-repeat`. In this situation, I need it all validation on the page consolidated into one place.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HrqsDOqA1m7Hooj43rSM?p=preview)

Also, is there some way I can make my person designation elements into a directive that behaves like a single input with a single name for validation?

Comment: Try to reproduce this in a fiddle

Comment: @RahilWazir I added a plunker

Comment: I think it has to do with having multiple inputs/selects with the same name.

Comment: @ptd right, i'm just not sure what to do about it.

Comment: What is the customer role for? Are their rules around that? I'm trying to figure out why it's there...

Comment: @couzzi it's just an example. My actual scenario has some different values. The point is, for a given scenario, I need some number of people assigned specific roles. I have to validate that all role requirements are met.

Comment: So a valid form is `1 employee`, `1 manager`, and `1 customer`—no repeats, no exclusions. Correct?

Comment: @couzzi more or less. In my actual scenario, I have some values that support multiple roles, and when that value is selected, no other person can be assigned any of the roles encompassed by the master role.